# In a Highcharts Stacked Area chart, is there a way of highlighting the area hovered over, rather than the area belonging to the nearest point?

Tags: highcharts

My issue with the Highcharts Stacked Area chart is in how it selects which series to highlight. It SEEMS to highlight the series associated with the nearest point, whereas I would like it to highlight the series the mouse is actually hovering over.

In the image below, the mouse is actually hovering over the area in light blue, but because the nearest point is in the dark blue series, it's highlighting that area.

[image: Stacked area chart, highlighting the area the cursor is NOT hovering over]

This causes an issue when you have multiple series stacked with very small and very high values (even zero). The user hovers a series with a large area, but the point it highlights might be associated with a series with no visible area (because it has a zero data point), and it will highlight the point with a tooltip saying something like "Switzerland: 0.00" rather than "Brazil: 9.999.99", even though you're hovering over Brazil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable `stickyTracking` and enable `trackByArea` options:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            ...,
            stickyTracking: false,
            trackByArea: true
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7ens45ot/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.stickyTracking

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.trackByArea

Comment: Thank you ppotaczek, much appreciated. Worked beautifully!